# Using lightbox: in Seaside's WAComponent appears in Halos but the browser doesn't show it?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

Just wanted to show the editor in a lightbox in the Ajax chapter [here](http://www.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/hirschfeld/seaside/tutorial)

```
StLoggedInComponent>>initializeMenuComponent
    self
        menuComponent:
            (StMenuComponent new
                addEntry: 'All' withAction: [ self showAllTasks ];
                addEntry: 'Completed' withAction: [ self showCompletedTasks ];
                addEntry: 'Pending' withAction: [ self showPendingTasks ];
                addEntry: 'Missed' withAction: [ self showMissedTasks ];
                addEntry: 'New Task' withAction: [ self createNewTask ];
                addEntry: 'Logout' withAction: [self session logout. self answer: true];
                yourself)

StLoggedInComponent>>createNewTask
    (self lightbox: self taskEditor newTask)
        ifFalse: [ ^ self ].
    self session database addTask: self taskEditor task toUser: self session user
```

The only thing I can figure it that by the time we reach this chapter the StLoggedInComponent is no longer the root component, switched to StRootTask in Task chapter. Could this be it, the lightbox: method implementation warns it will might work only when called from the root component? Inspecting the element in the browser shows the html is there but invisible, so it could just be the browser stumbling Scriptaculous, but downloaded an older Firefox 4 and the problem persists. Do I have to report it somehow in the children method somewhere?

Here is a print screen and the generated html:

[image: Screen capture showing the Seaside output with Halos enabled]

```
WADelegation
Browser
Inspector
Styles
Render / Source
<div class="generic">
  <h1>ToDo-List of xxx</h1>
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="/sttodo?_s=rLz5X40B6zq9NMsX&amp;_k=a2yB92XcFDp9dWq6&amp;6">All</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="/sttodo?_s=rLz5X40B6zq9NMsX&amp;_k=a2yB92XcFDp9dWq6&amp;7">Completed</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="/sttodo?_s=rLz5X40B6zq9NMsX&amp;_k=a2yB92XcFDp9dWq6&amp;8">Pending</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="/sttodo?_s=rLz5X40B6zq9NMsX&amp;_k=a2yB92XcFDp9dWq6&amp;9">Missed</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="/sttodo?_s=rLz5X40B6zq9NMsX&amp;_k=a2yB92XcFDp9dWq6&amp;10">New Task</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="/sttodo?_s=rLz5X40B6zq9NMsX&amp;_k=a2yB92XcFDp9dWq6&amp;11">Logout</a>
  </div>
  <div class="list" id="list">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input onclick="new Ajax.Updater(&quot;list&quot;,&quot;/sttodo&quot;,{&quot;evalScripts&quot;:true,&quot;parameters&quot;:[&quot;_s=rLz5X40B6zq9NMsX&quot;,&quot;_k=a2yB92XcFDp9dWq6&quot;,&quot;12&quot;].join(&quot;&amp;&quot;)})" type="checkbox" class="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>2 February 2016</td>
        <td>
          <div id="id15">Pending task</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <a href="/sttodo?_s=rLz5X40B6zq9NMsX&amp;_k=a2yB92XcFDp9dWq6&amp;16">edit</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="editor" id="editor">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input onclick="new Ajax.Updater(&quot;list&quot;,&quot;/sttodo&quot;,{&quot;evalScripts&quot;:true,&quot;parameters&quot;:[&quot;_s=rLz5X40B6zq9NMsX&quot;,&quot;_k=a2yB92XcFDp9dWq6&quot;,&quot;17&quot;].join(&quot;&amp;&quot;)})" type="checkbox" class="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>2 February 2016</td>
        <td>
          <div id="id20">Pending task</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <a href="/sttodo?_s=rLz5X40B6zq9NMsX&amp;_k=a2yB92XcFDp9dWq6&amp;21">edit</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="lightbox" style="display: none">
  <div class="generic lightbox">
    <h1>Editing task</h1>
    <form accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="/sttodo?_s=rLz5X40B6zq9NMsX&amp;_k=a2yB92XcFDp9dWq6">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Name: </td>
          <td>
            <input name="22" type="text" class="text"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Description: </td>
          <td>
            <textarea rows="auto" cols="auto" name="23"></textarea>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Deadline: </td>
          <td>
            <select name="24">
              <option value="1">January</option>
              <option value="2" selected="selected">February</option>
              <option value="3">March</option>
              <option value="4">April</option>
              <option value="5">May</option>
              <option value="6">June</option>
              <option value="7">July</option>
              <option value="8">August</option>
              <option value="9">September</option>
              <option value="10">October</option>
              <option value="11">November</option>
              <option value="12">December</option>
            </select>&nbsp;
            <input value="02" name="25" size="2" maxlength="2" type="text" class="text"/>&nbsp;
            <input value="2016" name="26" size="4" maxlength="4" type="text" class="text"/>
            <input name="27" type="hidden" class="hidden"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Completed: </td>
          <td>
            <select name="28">
              <option value="1">yes</option>
              <option value="2" selected="selected">no</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>
            <input name="29" value="Save" type="submit" class="submit"/>
            <input name="30" value="Cancel" type="submit" class="submit"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
New Session Configure Halos Profile Memory XHTML 0/4 ms
```

My Scriptaculous library works in other effects on the page, here it is:

```
initialize
    "self initialize"
 (WAAdmin
  register: self
  asApplicationAt: 'sttodo')
  addLibrary: PTDevelopmentLibrary;
  addLibrary: SUDevelopmentLibrary;
  addLibrary: StToDoLibrary;
  preferenceAt: #sessionClass put: StSession.
```

Evaluating Element.show("lightbox"); in the console shows the editor just below the list, no lightbox effect though. The response is this div contains the editor.

```
<div id="lightbox" style=""><div class="generic lightbox"><h1>Editing task</h1><form accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="/sttodo?_s=FqZr4RP_dLxEUf59&amp;_k=Ewy2Ngig00mj4yiH"><table><tbody><tr><td>Name: </td><td><input name="17" type="text" class="text"></td></tr><tr><td>Description: </td><td><textarea rows="auto" cols="auto" name="18"></textarea></td></tr><tr><td>Deadline: </td><td><select name="19"><option value="1">January</option><option value="2" selected="selected">February</option><option value="3">March</option><option value="4">April</option><option value="5">May</option><option value="6">June</option><option value="7">July</option><option value="8">August</option><option value="9">September</option><option value="10">October</option><option value="11">November</option><option value="12">December</option></select>&nbsp;<input value="02" name="20" size="2" maxlength="2" type="text" class="text">&nbsp;<input value="2016" name="21" size="4" maxlength="4" type="text" class="text"><input name="22" type="hidden" class="hidden"></td></tr><tr><td>Completed: </td><td><select name="23"><option value="1">yes</option><option value="2" selected="selected">no</option></select></td></tr><tr><td></td><td><input name="24" value="Save" type="submit" class="submit"><input name="25" value="Cancel" type="submit" class="submit"></td></tr></tbody></table></form></div></div>
```

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML? It's hard to tell what the problem might be just from looking at your code.

Comment: Edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific reason to start using Scriptaculous & Prototype now? ~5 years ago all new  development moved to jQuery, and a lot of what you're doing here does not translate so easy

Comment: Most of the tutorials are that old and haven't been updated. I'm following all of them one by one trying to learn and documenting errata, solutions, etc. I notify the owners and report bugs where I can. You might say it's my own way of helping out and keeping motivated. I did this for the Seaside book on book.seaside.st but commenting is disabled now and I can't report on anything anymore. The jQuery chapters need a lot of love, I even thought of updating the entire book but I don't know who has the "keys".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a method called `#lighter`:

```
lighter
^ 'updateLightbox();Event.observe(window,"resize",function(){updateLightbox();});'
```

This method calls the `updateLightbox()` function defined in the `#script` method. In the last line of that script you'll see
`Element.show("lightbox");`, which calls the scriptaculous `show()` function on the `lightbox` node. Take a look at your inspector and try to evaluate `Element.show("lightbox");` in the console. You should either see the lightbox or (more likely) an error message. I suspect that you might have included jQuery, which won't work with scriptaculous (scriptaculous requires Prototype).

To check wether you've included Prototype you can evaluate `$("lightbox")`. In Prototype this will return the node with the id `lightbox`, in jQuery it will be an empty jQuery object (since `"lightbox"` is interpreted as a CSS selector).

#### Update

I went and checked the lightbox code. There's indeed an error there, at least in the Seaside version distributed with the 3.1 one-click image. The problem is that the script is being interpreted as a JavaScript string and not as code. To see the effect (not as an actual fix) you can modify the method `WAScriptGenerator>>writeLoadScriptsOn:` as follows:

```
self loadScripts
    collect: [ :script|
        script isString
            ifTrue: [ JSStream on: script ]
            ifFalse:[ script ] ]   
        thenDo: [ :each |
            aDocument stream javascript: each.
            aDocument  nextPut: $; ]
```

The extra `#collect:` will ensure the correct encoding (quoting) of the script.

The problem is obviously that Seaside 3 introduced major changes to the JavaScript object model that weren't completed in case of the lightbox code and since most people nowadays use jQuery, this problem went unnoticed.

If you are subscribed to the Seaside mailing list, please drop a bug report there. If you're not, let me know and I can do that for you.

#### Update 2

The issue report for reference: https://github.com/SeasideSt/Seaside/issues/863

Comment: Used both Chrome and Safari and evaluated Element.show("lightbox"); in the Inspector->Console and the editor appears below the list, just normal WAComponent. Edited the question with details. I'm starting to think nothing is wrong, maybe the library is old and the effect no longer works as expected on newer browsers?

Comment: Also evaluated $("lightbox") and I get the HTML containing the editor, Prototype is working.

Comment: Great we managed to zero in to the bug. I added the code to my image, however the symptoms are the same, still no lightbox. Are you sure you didn't modify anything else?

Comment: Well, I didn't build your example. I tested the change with the `javascript/scriptaculous` test page, the "Example source" link there opens a lightbox. I suggest you try that out.

Comment: Had some more time to look deeper into the bug and click around. You fix seems to break most other "Example source" buttons in the examples. In javascript/scriptaculous try to go to the drag & drop menu at the top and click the button on those pages. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Again: this is **not** a fix. I simply wanted to show you where the problem lies. I've updated the snippet to also work for script objects and the example now works for me.

Comment: This actually fixed "everything" including my example from the book.seaside.st Works!!! Marked as the answer, it would be great to integrate the fix into Seaside.

Comment: Great. I'll post this to the Seaside list.

Answer (score 0):

There was a change from Seaside 3.0 to 3.1 where scripts should always be `JSObject` (sub)instances. Therefore, the fix should be to change the `lighter` method to:

```
lighter
    ^ JSStream on: 'updateLightbox();Event.observe(window,"resize",function(){updateLightbox();});'
```

A Smalltalk string now always is converted to a Javascript string. The change is because of this issue: https://github.com/SeasideSt/Seaside/issues/742 but it was not well documented indeed (sorry about that).